# SQL Server Temp Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, linked-server

Can anyone recommend a cool trick to create a linked server for some temporary work (selects with joins) and then destroy it after it's done? There are two different physical servers (one is MSSQL 2005 and one is SQL Server 2008) and I need to do some querying, after that the 2005 server will be switched out and I will have to do the same thing with a different 2005 server.

All thoughts appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple enough to script, have a look at the following stored procedures for creating and dropping linked servers

[sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

[sp_dropserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174310.aspx)